# Composing Operations on Streams in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

Let's say you have a program which manipulates a stream `Stream[Foo]` in some manner to produce a computation of interest, e.g.

```
myFooStream.map(toBar).groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
```

Lovely, except now you've got to do some other kind of computation on `myFooStream` like

```
myFooStream.map(toBar).sum
```

And you'd like to compose these computations somehow so that you do not need to iterate twice over the stream (let's say that iterating over the stream is expensive for some reason).

Is there some Scala-ish way of dealing with this problem? My problem, put more abstractly, is that I'd like to somehow abstract computation over these streams from the iteration over these streams. That is, what be best is if I could somehow write two methods `f: Stream[Foo] => Bar` and `g: Stream[Foo] => Baz` and somehow compose `f` and `g` in a way such that they operated on a single iteration of the stream.

Is there some abstraction which allows this?

UPDATED QUESTION: I've done a little digging around. Would scalaz arrows be helpful with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

`Streams` naturally try to avoid generating their elements multiple times if possible, by memoizing results.  From the [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream):

> The `Stream` class also employs memoization such that previously computed values are converted from Stream elements to concrete values of type `A`.

We can see that by construction a `Stream` that prints every time an element is produced, and running multiple operations:

```
val stream = Stream.from(0).map(x => { println(x); x }).take(10) //prints 0
val double = stream.map(_ * 2).take(5).toList //prints 1 through 4
val sum = stream.sum //prints 5 through 9
val sum2 = stream.sum //doesn't print any more
```

This works as long as you use a `val` and not a `def`:

> So long as something is holding on to the head, the head holds on to the tail, and so it continues recursively. If, on the other hand, there is nothing holding on to the head (e.g. we used `def` to define the `Stream`) then once it is no longer being used directly, it disappears.

This memoization means one must be cautious with `Streams`:

> One must be cautious of memoization; you can very quickly eat up large amounts of memory if you're not careful. The reason for this is that the memoization of the `Stream` creates a structure much like `scala.collection.immutable.List`.

Of course, if the generating of the items isn't what is expensive, but the actual traversal of the `Stream`, or memoization isn't available because it would be too expensive, one can always use `foldLeft` with a tuple, keeping track of multiple values:

```
//Only prints 0-9 once, even if stream is a def
val (sum, double) = stream.foldLeft(0 -> List.empty[Int]) { 
    case ((sum, list), next) => (sum + next, list :+ (next * 2)) 
}
```

If this is a common enough operation, you might even enrich `Stream` to make some of the more common operations like `foldLeft`, `reduceLeft`, and others available in this format:

```
implicit class RichStream[T](val stream: Stream[T]) extends AnyVal {
    def doubleFoldLeft[A, B](start1: A, start2: B)(f: (A, T) => A, g: (B, T) => B) = stream.foldLeft(start1 -> start2) { 
        case ((aAcc, bAcc), next) => (f(aAcc, next), g(bAcc, next)) 
    }
}
```

Which would allow you to do things like:

```
val (sum, double) = stream.doubleFoldLeft(0, List.empty[Int])(_ + _, _ :+ _)
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that streams held on to the head. The doubleFoldLeft is neat, but in my concrete case, it's going to get complicated. There will be a *lot* of computations that I need to chain together. This would get unwieldy without a powerful abstraction.

Comment: Also, when I tried to use a foldLeft keeping track of multiple values, I realized something: I had lost the benefits of higher-order functions. In other words, while I could ordinarily write something like myStream.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size) to create a map of counts, writing a foldLeft with a tuple meant I had to be in charge of incrementing the map. So I was dropping to a lower level of abstraction, and I want to have my functional cake and eat it too! :)

Comment: You're definitely losing some of your higher-order functions here, but that is natural when demanding extreme efficiency or very specific optimizations.  Are you sure you need this level of optimization?  Would `Stream's` natural memoization be enough?  Have you considered using a lower-level construct like a `for` comprehension?

Answer (score 1):

The stream will not iterate twice:

```
Stream.continually{println("bob"); 1}.take(4).map(v => v).sum
bob
bob
bob
bob
4
```

and

```
val bobs = Stream.continually{println("bob"); 1}.take(4)
val alices = Stream.continually{println("alice"); 2}.take(4)
bobs.zip(alices).map{ case (b, a) => a + b}.sum
bob
bob
bob
bob
alice
alice
alice
alice
12
```